# Is Android's WifiManager RSSI ScanResult.level consistent across different phones?

Tags: android, wifi

I am working on an Android Wi-fi fingerprinting application that uses the basestation signal RSSI values (returned as ScanResult.level) in units of dBm.

Are these level values consistent across different phones and chipsets? The Android document on [ScanResult.level](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#level) says: "The detected signal level in dBm. At least those are the units used by the TI driver."

Answer (score 0):

With an app I'm currently making, the Wi-Fi RSSI is consistent across different phones. However with bluetooth RSSI they are wildly different.. I get -75 for one phone, 170 for another. Some serious research is required I think!